# Django: Basic auth on only certain URL paths?

Tags: python, django, basic-authentication

I would like to password-protect only certain parts of my Django app with basic-auth. I'd like to protect all URLs except anything under `/api`.

I'm trying to use the [django-basicauth package](https://pypi.org/project/django-basicauth/) to do this.

I've configured it as follows. My app has three parts:

```
/api
/candc
/places
```

In `candc/localsettings.py` I've added:

```
BASICAUTH_USERS = {
  "myuser": "mypass"
}
```

The `candc/urls.py` file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('places.urls')),
    path('api/1.0/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

Then in my `places/views.py` file, I've added decorators to the URLs I want to protect, like this:

```
from basicauth.decorators import basic_auth_required

@basic_auth_required(
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
```

However, my app is asking for basic-auth protect on URLs under `/api` as well. (In fact it's not even showing the dialog, just returning 403s for any requests.)

The `api` app is using django-rest-framework, which I suspect may somehow be related to this problem.

How can I configure this so URLs under `/api` are not password-protected, but everything else is?

Answer (score 0):

As long as API urls are located in `candc/urls.py` they belong to the `candc` app. Therefore the settings for that app in `candc/localsettings.py` will apply for all API endpoints as well. So either you put your API stuff into a separate app (with separate `urls.py`) or you remove the `BASICAUTH_USERS` setting from `localsettings.py` and add `@basic_auth_required` to all views of the `candc` app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is probably related to the fact that you are using Django Rest Framework (DRF).  There is nothing you can do in the `urls.py` file to resolve this.  You need to change the way you have configured your API.  Luckily, this is pretty easy to do with DRF. You need to setup default authentication and permission classes so that permission is 'wide open'.

This easiest way to do this may depend on your version of DRF, but you should be able to get away with just adding this setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to share your `settings.py` file. In any case, you can completely remove all related fields in the **REST_FRAMEWORK** variable and remove the **DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES** field:

```
# in settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {}
```

Then you can specify the authentication class necessary before your view as such:

```
# in places/views.py
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication

@authentication_classes([BasicAuthentication])
def index(request):
    ...
```